# Настройка связки nginx + nodejs + socket.io + https

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, socket.io

**Привет всем!**
Помогите пожалуйста справиться с настройками сервера.

Исходные данные:
сервер на debian(не спрашивайте почему) с такими настройками:

1. nginx как прокси для отдачи статики
2. nodejs и сайт на нем + настроеный https

**У меня не получается:**

1. настроить редирект с http на https, так, чтобы при обращении к robots.txt и sitemap.xml они продолжали отдаваться по обоим протоколам.
2. настроить socket.io, из за nginx сервера, слиент socket.io не подключается выдавая ошибку 404/403(в зависимости от того или иного варианта настройки nginx), при том что *скрипт клиента socket.io по указанному пути напрямую открвыается*
3. настроить в nginx разводку адресов сайта по 2 серверам.

*Например:*

```
site.com/ - это будет 1 nodejs сервер  
site.com/about - это будет 1 nodejs сервер  
site.com/test - это будет 2 nodejs сервер
```

Ip пока будет общий, сертификат на домены/поддомены тоже(если это важно)

Заранее оговорюсь: **я пробовал очень много разных настроек и комбинаций этих настроек nginx сервера,** но то одно не работает, то другое
Если есть вопросы какие задавайте, я все что смогу поясню.

**Текущий конфиг nginx такой:**
*В конфиге SITE.COM - это замененный адрес, поэтому неважно, что слово написано большими буквами*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name SITE.COM www.SITE.COM;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location /robots.txt {
        root /home/alex/SITE.COM/www/public/;
    }
}

server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # Имя сервера
    server_name SITE.COM www.SITE.COM;

    # Путь к корневому каталогу проектов
    root /home/alex/SITE.COM/www;

    # нужно для linux-систем, чтобы правильно отдавались имена файлов на русском
    charset utf-8;

    # настроки для сертификатов
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_session_timeout 24m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 [2001:4860:4860::8888];

    # подключаем сертификаты Let's Encrypt
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/SITE.COM/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/SITE.COM/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/SITE.COM/chain.pem;

    # принуждаем перейти на https
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
#       return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    # основные настройки
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mp?4|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff2)$ {
        # Путь к корневому каталогу со статическими файлами
        root /home/alex/SITE.COM/www/public/;
    }

    # Логирование
    access_log /home/alex/SITE.COM/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/alex/SITE.COM/logs/nginx.error.log;
}
```